# Update taking too long

Tags: sql-server, performance, update

I am updating a table with 250 million rows in SQL Server, and it's been running for 4.5 days. I'd like to use the computer it's running on for other memory-intensive work, so I'm torn about whether to cancel the query (which might also take days, right?) or let it keep going. Does anyone see anything in the code below to make you think it's in a never ending loop or something? Will canceling it take so long it's not worth doing?

Here is the code:

```
update A.Large_Table
set [Large_Table].var1
= [Segment_Info].var1
from A.[Large_Table] left join [A].[Segment_Info]
on [Large_Table].id = [Segment_Info].id
where [Large_Table].var1 is null;
```

Var1 and id in both tables are integers. I have successfully done this query on a 100 million row table in the past, and it took maybe 2 hours, but in that case the join was performed on an 8-character string column (instead of the 'id' integer). I would have thought that switching to an integer would greatly improve performance and I could get the results for a larger table in comparable time.

Once I get past this run and either cancel or it finishes, I am aware of a few things to make this go better in the future (though it's not an operation I have to run often):

- Use insert into or select into a new table rather than update the existing one
- Move my log file to a different drive than the database (I'm still learning such basic things...)
- Restart SQL Server so the temp file clears

Any other things to try? Any of those above not likely to actually give a boost?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Perhaps a silly question to start us off, but are the "id" fields on each table unique on each table? I fear some sort of Cartesian Product situation might have developed if, for instance, one of your tables actually has duplicate "id" values within itself. Also, any reason why you're using a LEFT JOIN rather than an INNER?

Comment: What's the output from this query on your instance?
    select session_id, blocking_session_id, wait_type from sys.dm_exec_requests where session_id>51

This will let us know if your query is potentially blocked by another query, or what type of activity the query is waiting on (it might be IO, or Network, or something else)

Comment: Cancelling and rolling back can far more time than the length of the current query's runtime. Cancel and rollback is a 'mostly' single-threaded process, rather than what could currently be a multi-threaded `UPDATE`. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2008/09/12/sql-server-2000-2005-2008-recovery-rollback-taking-longer-than-expected.aspx

Comment: @Stuart session_id blocking_session_id wait_type
57 0 PAGEIOLATCH_EX
58 0 NULL

Comment: @Mark- 'id' is unique in the info table but not the large one being updated. So all records with the same id that are currently null in the large table should get the same value inserted, but that value is different for different 'id's. Left join because not all records in the large table are being updated, but I want to preserve them all in the results.

Comment: So you're duplicating data in every row for a single id? Why?

Comment: You could check sys.dm_exec_requests for that session_id that what's going on (status, logical_reads etc). Quite surprising if you have been able to run an update for 4.5 days without filling transaction log already...

Comment: Not directly answering your question but might help you on future similar situations. Before you run the update, try doing a select with the same conditions so you have a notion of what you are doing, like for instance:
`SELECT COUNT(*)
from A.[Large_Table] left join [A].[Segment_Info]
on [Large_Table].id = [Segment_Info].id
where [Large_Table].var1 is null;`

Comment: You may want to consider batching your updates in a loop or a cursor; say 10000 records at a time.  You'll still do a set based operation, just not all at once.  So, IDs 1 - 10000, then 10001 - 20000, etc.  It will run much quicker and limit the amount your Tlog gets pounded.

Comment: @Anna not to revive an old post, but i (like Aaron) am wondering why this data needs to be duplicated in this table. if it's a "staging" table then you may want to look into ETL. if it's not staging, you may want to consider a foreign key relationship here.

Answer (score 1):

Yikes, I'd be scared to look at your transaction log. This needs to be run in batches. You can experiment with that to determine the fastest runtime. What I like to do is strip out maybe a million or so records, then run updates in various batch sizes, like 1k, 2k, 5k, 10k, at a time to determine the quickest. I've done several hundred million row updates in an hour before. Then again, this also depends on the data size and I'm hoping you aren't messing around with blob fields.